# PhpStorm Making a Live template: Comma delimited string to associative array

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, I would like to highlight a string like this:

```
$entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display
```

And convert it to a string like the following with a live template:

```
    '$entity_type' => $entity_type,
    '$entity' => $entity,
    '$field' => $field,
    '$instance' => $instance,
    '$langcode' => $langcode,
    '$items' => $items,
    '$display' => $display,
```

I currently have a template that feels like it is a step away from what I desire.  My template currently can take a selected string and convert that string to a associative array element: `$entity_type` highlighted and using the live template command will convert this to `'$entity_type' => $entity_type,`.

My current live template code that takes a selection and converts it to a single php array element:

```
'$SELECTION$' => $SELECTION$,$END$
```

I became stuck attempting to guess how to use PhpStorm's [pre-defined functions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-template-variables.html).

I will often pull a string of arguments out of a function for debugging purposes and having a live template help me create an associative array faster would really speed up my world.

Edit:  I'm debugging for Drupal 7 if that makes a difference. Often I just need a quick function using a Devel function like this:

```
  dpm(array(
    '$entity_type' => $entity_type,
    '$entity' => $entity,
    '$field' => $field,
    '$instance' => $instance,
    '$langcode' => $langcode,
    '$items' => $items,
    '$display' => $display,
    '$elements' => $elements,
  ), 'mymodule_field_formatter_view');
```

Comment: Using standard functions available in Live Template -- nope. But PhpStorm now supports GroovyScript in Live Template: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155907#comment=27-1439617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using Live Templates in PhpStorm. You would have to split the selection by comma to a collection, then for each element in this collection, duplicate it and wrap the first occurrence with quotes. It doesn't look like there are functions for that in this feature.

> I will often pull a string of arguments out of a function for debugging purposes and having a live template help me create an associative array faster would really speed up my world.

The best tool for debugging purposes is a debugger. If you integrate XDebug with PhpStorm, you'll even see the values of the parameters directly in the editor. But, if you really just want to `var_dump()` the parameters to current function, just use `func_get_args()`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'll be checking xdebug out. In Drupal 7 I tend to use a lot of their dpm() and ddl() functions from the devel module.  I neglected to mention I was working within Drupal 7.